# how to monitor progress of uploading file in servlet 3.1

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

i want to monitor the progress of the file which is getting uploaded
i m using servlet 3.1

i know that by the specs of servlet 3.1 , i don't need apache common fileUpload
i can do that only by the Part class

i did this

```
InputStream inputStream = null; 

       double s;
       String size=null;
       String contentType=null;
       String submittedName=null;
       String tim=null;
       String actualLocation=null;
       System.out.println("getting it also here");
       Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
       System.out.println("getting it here");
       if(description.equals(""))
       {
           System.out.println("please provide some description about file");
       }
       else{

            if (filePart != null )
              {
                    s=(double)filePart.getSize();

                    double MB=(s/1048576);
                   if(MB != 0)

                       {
                             size=String.valueOf((float)MB);

                             contentType=filePart.getContentType();

                             submittedName=getFormatted(filePart.getSubmittedFileName());

                             tim=String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

                             actualLocation=name+"-"+commun+"-"+tim+"-"+submittedName;
                              System.out.println("getting it there");
                             inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
                              System.out.println("getting it here & there");

                                 try
                                 {
                                     File file=new File(x,actualLocation);
                                     Files.copy(inputStream, file.toPath());
                                  }
```

i know i can use a listener to monitor the progress , **but the main question is that where should i set progress listener** 
i thought it should be set with Part filePart.before System.out.println("getting it here")

[this is a screenshot of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F23B.jpg)

u can see that chrome is displaying the progress of uploading (in the bottom)(but i want a much more impressive progress bar)

when i ran my project i thought that in the console i'll see "getting it also here " while uploading but i found that control is not coming to that part unless uploading is completed.

i'm a bit confuse at which segment the uploading is happening and where should i set progress listener

Comment: @BalusC sir, is there no any way to do it in server side

Comment: and sir please tell me where exactly the uploading happening , i guess its not happening at Part filePart = request.getPart("file");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything in server side for upload progress bar. You can do that just using `javascript`, `html` and `css`.

If you are using `jQuery` take a look at this pugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/. Here is a file upload progress bar demo link http://malsup.com/jquery/form/progress.html. There are two more demos and plenty more examples in the website.

And you can take a look at this tutorial http://codular.com/javascript-ajax-file-upload-with-progress for doing this with `html5` and `javascript`. Just ignore the `PHP` part.

You should not have to change anything in your `java` code, cause the `servlet` method will be hit after the file upload has been completed.